# Removing automatic parentheses around references with linguex

Tags: cross-referencing, linguex

When I use the \ref command, I automatically get parentheses around the cross-referenced number. I think it's because I'm using the linguex package for examples. I want to not have the parentheses show up automatically so that I can manually add subexample letters inside parentheses -- e.g. (5a) -- when the a wasn't ever part of a list that can be labeled. (Specifically, I need this to reference candidates in OT tableaux, which I make in tabular, which doesn't lend itself to list environments...as far as I can tell.)

Here's (what I hope is) a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \label{test} Here's an example

I want to reference \ref{test} without getting parentheses around it automatically.

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 4 of `linguex`, the delimiters around the number in the example and in the references can be separately customized:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\theExLBr}{}
\renewcommand{\theExRBr}{}

\begin{document}

\ex. \label{test} Here's an example

I want to reference \ref{test} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The default definition is of course

```
\newcommand{\theExLBr}{(}
\newcommand{\theExRBr}{)}
```

There are also `\ExLBr` and `\ExRBr` for the delimiters around the example number.

Comment: how do I do this for selected examples without having to keep redefining theexlbr

Answer (score 3):

Redefining `\theExLbr` and `\theExRbr` works "globally" by changing all occurrence of all labels. If you want to use `\ref` with parentheses most of the time and only need a one-off fix, you might consider editing the string returned by `\ref`. This requires `xstring` and `refcount` (the latter is also imported by `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount, xstring}

\usepackage{linguex}
\newcommand{\myref}[2][]{%
  \refused{#2}%
  \StrSubstitute{\getrefnumber{#2}}{)}{#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

\ex.\label{sent1}
\a. Sentence 1
\b. Sentence 2

Sentences \myref[a,b]{sent1} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!